# Can I add two URLs in the facebook webhook Callback URL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-webhooks

I am using the same APP for the development, staging, and production environment. And I have configured a webhook for "Application". Now I have added the development URL for testing purposes, it works perfectly but how to add staging and production environment URLs?

Answer (score 1):

No, you can not add multiple callback URLs, it only takes a single one.

You might want to look into creating test apps - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/development/build-and-test/test-apps

> Test apps are child apps created from other, non-child apps. They are primarily used to clone apps that are already in Live mode in order to test new reviewable permissions and features without compromising the functionality of the cloned app.

> Test apps are always in Development mode and inherit their parent app settings at the time that they are created. Once created, you can adjust a test app's settings to suit your testing needs.